# What setting controls moving the cursor on the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line

On some Unix systems, I can type Ctrl-A or Ctrl-E to move to the beginning or end of the line.  On some Unix systems I can not and it just prints ^A or ^E, etc.  What controls whether this keystoke works as I expect (move around the command line), or prints the ^A, ^E, etc. character?

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on specific shell implementation (you might have different default shell on different systems or even for different users within a single system, e.g. bash, ksh, tcsh, etc).

Also it depends on shell itself.

E.g. bash supports two modes: emacs and vi. Each mode has its own shortcuts (emacs or vi  like). To change it you have to execute `set -o emacs` (normally it's a default one) or `set -o vi`

You can find more information in your specific shell documentation.

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr

```
set -o emacs
```

will enable the Ctrl-A, Ctrl-E, Ctrl-B, etc emacs key bindings in most shells you're likely to use.

---

The shell may not have any line editing capabilities, or may be in the `vi` editing mode (the only one specified by the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_13_03)).

When not in `emacs` editing mode, the Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E have no special significance. If the `echo` and `echoctl` stty/termios setting are on, all control keys which are not handled specially will be displayed in the `^A`, `^X`, etc, "caret" notation.

Many shells (like `ksh` or `zsh`) will determine the default editing mode (vi or emacs) based on the values of `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` environment variables (in this order of precedence, and also handling variants like `vim`, `elvis`, `xemacs`, etc).

This was broken (very annoyingly!) in `mksh`, but it's also still the case in other `pdksh`-derived shells.

Other shells like `bash` or `tcsh` default to the `emacs` editing mode, but that may also be overridden from the configuration file of the line editing library.

For the [`readline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html#INITIALIZATION_FILE) library used by `bash` and many other programs, the configuration files is `~/.inputrc` (or a file specified in the `INPUTRC` environment variable) with a fallback to `/etc/inputrc` and the settings are:

```
set editing-mode vi
set editing-mode emacs
```

For the `editline`/`libedit`[1] library used by many BSD programs, the configuration file is usually [`~/.editrc`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/editrc) and the settings are:

```
bind -v  # for vi
bind -e  # for emacs
```

[1] not to be confused with the [`libeditline`](https://github.com/troglobit/editline) readline "work-alike" which only provides an emacs editing-mode.